# How can I start a process with parameters in a cgroup?

Tags: linux

I can start a process in a cgroup with

```
user:vi    cpuset testgroup
```

in `cgrules.conf`

but how can I do it with parameters?
for example only when I open the file `test123` with `vi`

```
user:vi test123 cpuset testgroup
```

does not work

```
user:"vi test123" cpuset testgroup
```

does not work either

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the next commamd:

```
sudo cgexec -g cpu:cpulimited /usr/local/bin/matho
```

While not exactly the solution to your question, the following blog post may present you with some insights on how this works:
https://scoutapm.com/blog/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups